# How can own commands be aware of \global?

Tags: macros, tex-core, grouping

When I define a command that defines commands

```
\def\makefoobar{
  \def\foo{foo}
  \def\bar{bar}
}
```

and prefix it with `\global`

```
{ \global\makefoobar }
```

it is treated like

```
{
  \global\def\foo{foo}
  \def\bar{bar}
}
```

keeping the `\global` effect only to the first definition, or more precise, the first token of `\makefoobar`, may this be a definition or not.

Is there a way to define `\makefoobar` so that modifiers like `\global` or `\long` would affect all macros defined within, or can I only define a global alternative command `\gmakefoobar`?

Comment: Short answer: no; prefixes like `\global`, `\long`, `\outer` and `\protected` (the last one is in e-TeX) only apply to the next token (and they do expansion because a proper token should follow them).

Answer (score 18):

You could use

```
{ \globaldefs=1 \makefoobar }
```

All assignments are global while `\globadefs` is non zero. Beware though, lots of things will break with the setting, use with care.

Comment: +1 Thank you for teaching me `\globaldefs`.  Seems like I skipped it when reading TeXbook.

Comment: I indeed fear things may break with `\globaldefs`, especially when the macro used may include other macros, which would then be affected as well, and was thus hoping for a solution to propagate the `\global` into own macros. Last resort would be to define a `\gmakefoobar` similar to `\gdef`.

Comment: @XZS the setting of `\globaldefs` is itself local so if used as above it only affects the two definitions inside your macro

Answer (score 8):

```
\def\makefoobar#1{%
  #1\def\foo{foo}%
  #1\def\bar{bar}%
}
```

Now you can use one of

```
\makefoobar{}
\makefoobar{\global}
\makefoobar{\global\long}
```

or all the other combinations.

The prefixes `\global`, `\long`, `\outer` and `\protected` (the last one only if the engine uses e-TeX extensions) only apply to the next token and they do expansion because they must be followed by a proper token.

We could add an abstraction layer.

```
\def\multipledef#1#2{%
  \def#1##1{\def\prefixes{##1}#2}%
}
\def\pdef{\prefixes\def}

\multipledef\makefoobar{%
  \pdef\foo{foo}%
  \pdef\bar{bar}%
}

% tests follow

\makefoobar{}
\show\foo\show\bar

{\makefoobar{\global\long}}
\show\foo\show\bar

\makefoobar{\protected}
\show\foo\show\bar
```

Here's the session on the terminal (compile with `pdftex` because of `\protected`):

```
> \foo=macro:
->foo.
l.12 \show\foo
              \show\bar
? 
> \bar=macro:
->bar.
l.12 \show\foo\show\bar

? 
> \foo=\long macro:
->foo.
l.15 \show\foo
              \show\bar
? 
> \bar=\long macro:
->bar.
l.15 \show\foo\show\bar

? 
> \foo=\protected macro:
->foo.
l.18 \show\foo
              \show\bar
? 
> \bar=\protected macro:
->bar.
l.18 \show\foo\show\bar

?
```